# Tkinter: New window has nothing in it even after writing code for it

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The user clicks on "Register", and then a new window appears however nothing is in it.

Here is my code, I thought this would make everything appear?

```
    def create_regwindow(self):
      t = tk.Toplevel(self)
      t.wm_title("Register")
      t.field_user = tk.Label(self, text="Username")
      t.field_pass = tk.Label(self, text="Password")

      t.entry_user = tk.Entry(self)
      t.entry_pass = tk.Entry(self, show="*")

      t.field_user.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.E)
      t.field_pass.grid(row=1, sticky=tk.E)
      t.entry_user.grid(row=0, column=1)
      t.entry_pass.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC BY-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 2):

You are setting parents as `self`. You should use `t` as parent on new widgets to make them appear on `t`.

```
t.field_user = tk.Label(t, text="Username") 
t.field_pass = tk.Label(t, text="Password")
```